# Ground Detection in Unity Movement Script Won't Work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, game-development

I need help with my unity project. I'm new to gamedev and decided to brute force a mario game in order to learn some basics. However, I have gotten caught up at making a movement script. I figured out with some ease how to make my mario character go left and right, but I'm having trouble with my jumping. I can jump, but i JUST CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO GROUND DETECTION FOR IT. I would include some code example, but i've tried so many things, I don't know what I would even include. Please just take the time to help me out by pasting a link to a copy of your movement script, so I could hopefully work off that. Thanks!

Edit:
It's still not working and i don't really know why
Here's my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mario : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator animator;
    SpriteRenderer spriterenderer;

    bool pushingButton;
    bool isGrounded;
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;
    [SerializeField]
    float jumpForce;



    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        spriterenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }



    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(_transform.position, GroundChecker.postion, whatIsFloor);




        if (Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            pushingButton = true;
        }

        else
            pushingButton = false;





        if (Input.GetKey("left") && Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Idle");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("right") && Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Jump");
            spriterenderer.flipX = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Walk");
            spriterenderer.flipX = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }


        if (Input.GetKey("left") && Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Idle");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("left") && Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Jump");
            spriterenderer.flipX = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Walk");
            spriterenderer.flipX = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("up") && isGrounded)
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Jump");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        if (pushingButton == false)
        {
            animator.Play("Mario Idle");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer this question unless you show us the code you currently have, no matter how broken, because we have no idea how you have implemented player movement in your game.

Answer (score 2):

create a gameobject "groundCheck", make it child of character and place it below character's feet
    // LayerMask to determine what is considered ground for the player
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

```
// Transform just below feet for checking if player is grounded
public Transform groundCheck;

void Update()
{

    /* Check to see if character is grounded by raycasting from the middle of the player down to the groundCheck position and see if collected with gameobjects on the whatIsGround layer */

    isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(_transform.position, groundCheck.position, whatIsGround);

    // If grounded AND jump button pressed, then allow the player to jump

    if (isGrounded && CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
    {
        DoJump();
    }
}
```